# Retrieving the Distance "dis" result from a Near query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've set up a geo-spacial query that works beautifully, however I'm looking to get the distance for each of the results.

Given the query:

```
var query = Query.Near("Location", longitude, latitude);
var places = mongoDb.GetCollection<Place>("places").Find(near);
```

how do I retrieve the distance from each element in "places"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can get the distance from mongo, but what I have done in the past was just using the Haversine formula to get the distance after I had the data.

You can find the implementation that I used 
[here](http://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/haversine-formula-in-c/)

**EDIT**: Sorry you can get the distance back from Mongo, but not with Query.Near(). You need to use the GeoNear function that is on the collection.

```
 mongoDb.GetCollection<Place>("places").GeoNear(Query.Null, latitude, longitude, maxDistance);
```

This will return a `GeoNearResult<Place>` which will have a Hits property that is  `IEnumurable<Hit>` that will contain a Distance property and a document property that will contain your place object.

Comment: You are a life saver, works like a charm. Although now I need to go lookup what measurement that is, maybe radians?

Comment: Yeah it will likely be in radians, in the MongoDB documentation they say it's roughly 69 miles per radian. But that is only at the equator.  You can find more information here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-TheEarthisRoundbutMapsareFlat