# C# MongoDB driver 2.0 - Getting distance back from near query

Tags: c#, mongodb, geolocation, location, distance

I am doing a NearSphere query with the C# MongoDB driver 2.0 and it works fine.
The results are ordered by distance automatically but I would like to get that distance back for each of the search results to be able to display it back.
I found this post that says how to do it for the old version of the driver [Retrieving the Distance "dis" result from a Near query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810458/retrieving-the-distance-dis-result-from-a-near-query) but didn't manage to find how to do it with the new drivers.

This is my code:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<MyType>("myTypes");
var locFilter = Builders<MyType>.Filter.NearSphere(x => x.GeoLocation, criteria.Long, criteria.Lat, criteria.RadiusInMiles/3963.2);
var results = await collection.Find(locFilter).ToListAsync();
```

I guess I have to do something before calling ToList on the IFindFluent result ?

Any help ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The basic [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator as is implemented here ( under the hood ) does not return the "distance" from the point or object given. You might need to use more direct methods of calling: 1: either aggregation [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) or the 2: [**geoNear**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) database command form, which both return the distance as a field within the returned document results

Comment: thanks for the help ! I'm struggling to find the way to do that with the C# 2.0 driver though. If you have an example would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Just getting me now because the comment was opposed to an "answer" because I'm going to bed. All drivers support basic ways of submitting `.aggregate()` pipelines or basic `db.command` statements if you just look for the methods

Comment: I know this is an old post but was this ever solved? I have a very similar problem trying to use aggregation but can't seem to get it working with nearsphere. Would love to know the status of this

Comment: I'm going to write the answer now, I hope you find it useful

Comment: Is there anyway I could fully use `Builders` approach? Because I am getting a weird behavior and only few documents following the answer

Answer (score 6):

The C# MongoDB Driver lacks of some operations but the reality there's not any restriction querying the database. The methods Project, Match and so forth are just helpers to build a PipeLine that's exactly a BsonDocument like any other.

I had to query the database from C# using a similar approach to yours:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate( 
[ { $geoNear : 
   { near : { type : "Point", coordinates : [-34.5460069,-58.48894900000001] }, 
    distanceField : "dist.calculated",  maxDistance : 100, 
    includeLocs : "dist.location",
    num : 5,  spherical : true   } 
  } , 
  { $project : {_id: 1, place_id:1, name:1, dist:1} } 
] ).pretty()
```

As you know there's not a geoNear method to build it in the driver, so you can just create the BsonDocument.
To show you that everything can be built in that way find below a sample query from C# not using the project clausule either, I built it from the BsonDocument. You can push BsonDocument's in the pipeline as you wish.

```
var coll = _database.GetCollection<UrbanEntity>("mycoll");
var geoNearOptions = new BsonDocument {
    { "near", new BsonDocument {
        { "type", "Point" }, 
        { "coordinates", new BsonArray {-34.5460069,-58.48894900000001} },
        } },
    { "distanceField", "dist.calculated" },
    { "maxDistance", 100 }, 
    { "includeLocs", "dist.location" },  
    { "num", 5 },  
    { "spherical" , true }
};

var projectOptions = new BsonDocument {
    { "_id" , 1 }, 
    { "place_id", 1 }, 
    { "name" , 1 }, 
    { "dist", 1}
};

var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>();
pipeline.Add( new BsonDocument { {"$geoNear", geoNearOptions} });
pipeline.Add( new BsonDocument { {"$project", projectOptions} });

using(var cursor = await coll.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(pipeline)) {
    while(await cursor.MoveNextAsync()) {
        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current) {
            // Here you have the documents ready to read
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway I could fully use `Builders` approach? Because I am getting a weird behavior and only few documents following the answer

Comment: Are you using only Builders syntax?

Comment: I have almost 100 req across my 28 collections and as for now yes... :(

Comment: Builders are only wrappers to construct BsonDocuments, just a helper. Which strange behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Hmm now it seems to work, the documentation is pointing that you should precise the field to search over if there is only one index. However I get DIST along the fields of my document which makes it undeserializable ...

Comment: Those builders are tricky, I used them a lot and for a while I preferred to build the bson document myself